# Magento 1.9 the changes in core/Mage/Sales/wsdl.xml not working?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, soap-api-v2

I have changed directly the core **sales/wsdl.xml** and **wsi.xml** files to add a custom column value in **order_info** and **order_list** of S**OAP API** V2 but it doesn't appear, Please help me. I am stuck.

Comment: Anyone, please help me

Comment: Is there any way to troubleshoot this?